# If Matrix A, B are similar,Find the invertible matrix P such that $B=PAP^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, reference-request, linear-transformations, transition-matrix

Given Matrix $A \sim B$ , If Matrix A, B are similar,Find the invertible matrix P such that $B=PAP^{-1}$
$$ 
A = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -2 & 1  \\
2 & 3 & -2 \\
0 & 0& -2  \\
\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad
B = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
Find the invertible matrix P such that $B=PAP^{-1}$
Seek the guidance of the great God,Best is a smarter solution

Answer (score 1):

Here $A = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -2 & 1  \\
2 & 3 & -2 \\
0 & 0& -2  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda=-2,-1,2$.

Now for eigenvectors $X$, we have to solve $(A-\lambda I)X=0$

For $\lambda = -2$, $\qquad(A+2 I)X=0\implies \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 & 1  \\
2 & 5 & -2 \\
0 & 0& 0  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1  \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
x_1  \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1  \\
2 \\
4
\end{bmatrix}$

For $\lambda=-1$, $\qquad(A+I)X=0\implies \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -2 & 1  \\
2 & 4 & -2 \\
0 & 0& -1  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1  \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
x_1  \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-2  \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

For $\lambda=2$, $ \qquad(A-2 I)X=0\implies \begin{bmatrix}
-4 & -2 & 1  \\
2 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0& -4  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1  \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
x_1  \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1  \\
2 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

The $P$ matrix is just the matrix of eigenvectors of $A$.

Thus $P=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -2 & -1  \\
2 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 0& 0  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Now $P^{-1}=-\frac{1}{12}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & -3  \\
8 & 4 & 0 \\
-4 & -8& 3  \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1  \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & -8& 3  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Therefore $PAP^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -2 & -1  \\
2 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 0& 0  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -2 & 1  \\
2 & 3 & -2 \\
0 & 0& -2  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1  \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & -8& 3  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$=\begin{bmatrix}
-28 & -44 & 13  \\
14 & 31 & -14 \\
-32 & -40 & 4  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

After some operations, $$\begin{bmatrix}
-28 & -44 & 13  \\
14 & 31 & -14 \\
-32 & -40 & 4  \\
\end{bmatrix}\equiv\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2  
\end{bmatrix}=B$$